# NPE in MediaSessionCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I encounter this crash after upgrading the support library to 25.3.1 :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Callback$StubApi21.onCommand(Unknown Source:941)
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi21$CallbackProxy.onCommand(Unknown Source:164)
   at android.media.session.MediaSession$CallbackMessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSession.java:1363)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This crash only happens to API > 21. It seems that mSessionImpl in MediaSessionCompat.Callback class is null, but I can't find a way where this situation can happen.

Has anyone already experienced this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems fixed in the 25.4.0